# Bean injection based on a local method parameter

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring and am facing a curious problem. Say I have the following:

```
class StatsCollector {
private final List<Stat> stats;
private UserId userId;
.
.
.
public void findUserId() {
    userId = UserService.getUserId();
}

public void compileStats() {
    stats.stream().forEach(stat -> {
        stat.fetchStats();
    });
}
```

}

I am using spring and I want to inject different List of Stat's based on different userId. Say my spring configuration has:

```
<util:list id="ATypeStats">
    <value>fooA</value>
    <value>barA</value>
</util:list>

<util:list id="BTypeStats">
    <value>fooB</value>
    <value>barB</value>
</util:list>
```

Question: Is it possible to inject either ATypeStats or BTypeStats based on the userId in the code after getting it from the service?

My problem is that I cannot know the userId in advance to use constructor injection in any way. The userId is obtained using the service and then I need to inject required list from the spring configuration.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but why don't you do `stats.forEach(Stat::fetchStats);`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will do. But that is not my actual issue :)

Comment: You can inject both of lists, and make decision, which one to use after you've got id.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would opt not to have "data" like user-stats in the spring config. I would probably create a proper service that does stat lookup by user id.

Depending on your actual scenario there are a few ways to accomplish something like that:
If only one user stat list is valid for a given application instance:
You can use profiles/environments to conditionally load different configs  or parts of configs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) and combine this with an alias.

Alternatives to the "real" user service are injecting a map (maps get populated with  for a given type) or injecting the whole application context and manually fetching the data. I would however consider these as "lazy hacks" when a proper service to do the lookup would be better suited (and both obviously are not as flexible, testable and scaleable as a proper service)